# mongodb- Push query results into variable

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to push/insert query results into variable. It gives me error for both the below cases. However, the queries individually gives me correct result. The error is only when trying to push the value into variable.
Can you identify what is wrong with the queries?

```
var aggVal =db.zeroDimFacts.aggregate(
    {$group: {_id: '', maxi: {$max: "$_id"}}},
    {$project: {_id:0, maxe:"$maxi"}})
printjson(aggVal)

var ss = db.zeroDimFacts.find({},{_id:1}).sort({"_id": -1}).limit(1)
printjson(ss)
```

Both the codes give some similar errors like:

```
DBQuery: Agronomics.zeroDimFacts -> { "query" : { }, "orderby" : { "_id" : 1 } }
```

Comment: How do you intend on pushing `aggVal` and `ss` variables? Can you show us your expected output or final result? Also, the [**`aggregate()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method takes in an array as the pipeline argument, here you are providing it a document.

Comment: All I wanted is to get the maximum _id value from the collection. In my case it should me 600116. You can give me the best query as per performance to get this. Something like: var maxVal = <mongo-shell code> print(maxVal) should be the result of the mongo-shell code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the aggregation framework you would need to run the following pipeline;

**Note** - the pipeline should be an array of aggregation operators piped together

```
var cursor = db.zeroDimFacts.aggregate([
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "maximumId": { "$max": "$_id" } } }
]);
var maximumId = cursor.toArray()[0]["maximumId"];
printjson(maximumId);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be perfect way to get max value. However, it still continues to give correct result.
If someone can provide/ suggest a correct way, I will mark it as answer after two days.

After a long trial n errors, I have found an answer to this. First push the values into an array and the zeroth element of an array will have your max value. Now push that value to another variable.

```
var ss = db.zeroDimFacts.find({},{_id:1}).limit(1).sort({_id:-1}).toArray()
var vi =Number(ss[0]._id)
print(vi)
```

Comment: Correction : I would wait for two days before I mark my hack as an answer. Meanwhile , if someone can give more appropriate answer that can be marked.